# Base Template in reusable Django App

Tags: django, django-templates, reusability

I want create a reusable app from a custom project.

The part I want to move to a reusable app serves whole pages and uses this at the top:

`{% extends "myproject/base.html" %}`

Now I am unsure what base template to use. In the new reusable app, I don't want to use `myproject` since this is custom code which I can't share.

I tried to get help from the great django docs, but could not find a solution - Forgive me if I was blind :-)

What to write here in a reusable app?

`{% extends ??????? %}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store those templates within the app folder.

Assuming you have a structure like `myproject/myreusableapp` you would create a templates folder inside myreusableapp folder and store your `base.html` file there.

You would then extend that file `{% extends "myreusableapp/base.html" %}`

Comment: I don't have the directory structure `myproject/myreusableapp` since I want myreusableapp to be a pip-installable python package. But `{% extends "myreusableapp/base.html" %}` looks good. ...... But wait. How does "myreusableapp/base.html" look like? I guess it should use some kind of "extend" to get the header+footer of the containing project.

Comment: django-allauth is a great example of a package that has templates involved. Maybe take a look at that code to get a real example, inside the `allauth/templates` directory.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

Comment: thank you for the link. The pattern is that "myreusableapp/base.html" contains one line: `{% extends "base.html" %}`. See https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/base.html

Comment: Do media requirements (JS/CSS files) from forms and widgets get into the response?

Comment: @guettli not sure about including css/js

Comment: I am surprised. There is no sane and default way for this in django. I have no clue how to include form media, too.  I ask myself how reusable apps are possible at all. Most django packages I use are only Fields or Widgets at the moment. These don't render whole pages. But packges providing only widgets are no apps in my eyes. They are libraries. Apps render whole pages ... Naming things is the most difficult part of computer science :-)

Comment: most 3rd party apps don't touch templates because everyone does template styling differently. The few 3rd party apps that do have templates either provide raw, unstyled templates (django-allauth) and allow users to override them, or provide template packs (django-crispy-forms) which are based off of well-known css libraries such as bootstrap or materialize, as well as ability to extend with more template packs if necessary. Bottom line is that all the py code can be the same, but everyone typically needs to style templates differently, so those aren't seen as much in reusable app packages.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately django does not offer an official convention here.

There is a third party documentation project which defines these rules for reusable templates:

https://django-reusable-app-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apps/templates.html

The issue to get a convention in the official django docs is open since 2012:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19106

Here is my ticket, which was closed as duplicate of above:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26501

... I hope an agreement will be found in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way :

```
\project
|
+-\main
| |
| +-\template
| | |
| | +-\mainapp
| |   |
| |   +-base.html
| |   +-index.html
| |   +-...
| |
| +-\static
|   |
|   +-css
|   +-js
|   +-pics
|   +-...
|
+-\otherapp
  |
  +-...
```

Where `main` is an app for standard operations (pager, login,...) and has the base templates and static for in it. Note that templates are stored in `main/templates/main/`.

In project `settings.py`, don't forget to register `main/static` in the `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Then you can deploy using `{% extends 'main/base.html' %}`.

Comment: I understand this like this: If you reuse "otherapp" in a different project called "main2" then "main2" provides its base template as "main/base.html". OK, looks like this roughly the same as the solution provided by awwester. Please correct me if I am missing something.